# og:image not big enough

Tags: image, facebook-opengraph

I have read about how to use og:image and image size requirements. I am using a 799x639 px image, but FB debugger still says "Provided og:image is not big enough".

Said image is NOT on the page itself, but in a subdirectory of the site.

Here is how I wrote the Meta Tag:

"og:image" content="http://www.sanzalangola.com/images/sanza_og.png"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, your image URL doesn't exist, maybe that's it?